# How to estimate the online training complexity of neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, time-complexity, big-o, training-data

suppose I am having a neural network with the following structure

Input layer:10 neuron

Hidden layer 1: 20 neuron with relu activation function
Batch normalization

Hidden layer 2: 30 neuron with relu activation function
Batch normalization

Hidden layer 3: 40 neuron with relu activation function
Batch normalization

Output layer : 4 neuron with logistic regression

Then how to calculate the big O complexity for **online training** of it ?

The training is assume to be back propagation

Thank you for your enthusiast

Answer (score 0):

O(2^n) to converge to optimal solution.